# Using divs for table-like layout, how to highlight certain divs with CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am using divs to create a table-like layout. I am trying to mimic a table row being highlighted but with a div approach. Is there an easy way to do this with css/jquery instead of throwing attributes on every div?

Here is css i am using to highlight a div.  I am also looking for the first 'column' to be highlighted as well in the appropriate row...

So if i am in the second column of inputs, in the second row, i want that one to be highlighted and the corresponding label.

```
.dinfo > div:hover
{
background: #eee;
}
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6dFqd/

Comment: this looks tabular. why aren't you using tables?

Comment: i am using knockout as well and the markup is ugly using tables, this is a simplified version.

Answer (score 0):

I would switch to tables.  Use `:nth-child()` pseudoclass in CSS to style elements.

An example is `table tr:nth-child(odd) {}`

You can also put numbers in place of odd or even.

Comment: The OP commented "i am using knockout as well and the markup is ugly using tables, this is a simplified version."

Comment: I posted the above before he made that comment, check the time stamps.